# TanStack Query Devtools v5

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

Do you have any idea why TanStack Query Devtools render like that? It is version 5.22.2.
[image]

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example of your app? Taking a look into your code will help us better understand your problem and provide a solution. Consider adding a link to a code sandbox with your project setup

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can´t share the code because it is a private project :-(  It is a React application upon a custom dev stack. After some exploration, I think that the problem might be with content security policy or something like that. Version 4 works correctly.

Comment: I see. In that case, maybe sharing some logs from the console or the network tab might be useful since it seems like the stylesheets for `react-query` devtools are not being loaded

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am running a simple project and the situation with styles is different. I can inspect them in the browser´s console and everything works like a charm. The sad part is that in the project, where the dev tools don´t work, there are no errors in the browser´s console.